# no 'jcode' gem when running rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I try to run 'rails server' it's giving me an error saying that it can't find 'jcode', and I think jcode is a default ruby lib.
Do you guys have any clue as to whats going on?

```
/Users/seanfchan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/gdata-1.1.1/lib/gdata.rb:21:in `require': no such file to load -- jcode (LoadError)
 from /Users/seanfchan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/gdata-1.1.1/lib/gdata.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
 from /Users/seanfchan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/contacts-1.2.4/lib/contacts/gmail.rb:1:in `require'
 from /Users/seanfchan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/contacts-1.2.4/lib/contacts/gmail.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
 from /Users/seanfchan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/contacts-1.2.4/lib/contacts.rb:6:in `require'
 from /Users/seanfchan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/contacts-1.2.4/lib/contacts.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
 from /Users/seanfchan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:64:in `require'
 from /Users/seanfchan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in require'
 from /Users/seanfchan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:62:in `each'
 from /Users/seanfchan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:62:in `block in require'
 from /Users/seanfchan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:51:in `each'
 from /Users/seanfchan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:51:in `require'
 from /Users/seanfchan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler.rb:112:in `require'
 from /Users/seanfchan/RubyPractice/gettingContancts/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
 from /Users/seanfchan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
 from /Users/seanfchan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `block in <top (required)>'
 from /Users/seanfchan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
 from /Users/seanfchan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
 from script/rails:6:in `require'
 from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

System: Mac OSx Snow Leopard
Ruby: RVM 1.9.2
Rails: 3.0.1
Gem: 1.3.7
trying to use 'contacts' gem

Thanks,
Sean Chan

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sounds like the library you're using wasn't updated for Ruby 1.9.

Ruby >= 1.9 doesn't have jcode, a module to handle japanese (EUC/SJIS) strings, as it supports unicode natively.

You may want to see of a newer version of the library is available, otherwise you can look at the source and find where it is requiring jcode, and replace it with

```
require 'jcode' if RUBY_VERSION < '1.9'
```

Comment: I'm new to ruby, and got the same error. Can you please tell me the exact file where to put this code??

Comment: @Bongs: The error message tells you exactly what file and line.

Answer (score 5):

We should check the lib folder which is presented under the gdata gem file.

Add this line:

```
require 'jcode' if RUBY_VERSION < '1.9'
```

in the `lib/gdata.rb` file.

Answer (score 2):

Other solution, put this in your gemfile:

```
gem 'gdata_19', '1.1.5'
gem 'contacts', :git => 'git@github.com:eofferma/contacts.git'
```

Comment: I just had to switch to: gem 'gdata_19', '1.1.5'